# Google Maps getBounds() Returning illegal values

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, parse-platform

I m using google maps api.
and have called map.getBounds() inside event "bounds_changed".

I m not able to inderstand the value that I m getting.

```
{
    "O": {
        "O": 34.83243634643437,
        "j": 40.622842157331945
    },
    "j": {
        "j": -124.47192400611777,
        "O":-120.35205095924277
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of this value. I want to convert it to North East and South West Points.

Thanks

UPDATE::

```
b = map.getBounds(); 
var bounds = { "ne": b.getNorthEast(), "sw": b.getSouthWest() }; 
console.log("Map Bounds: ", JSON.stringify(bounds));
```

Result: `Map Bounds: , {"ne":{},"sw":{}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a LatLngBounds object. You don't need to understand what you get if you output it to the console. Simply call `getNorthEast()` and `getSouthWest()` on it to get your points.

e.g.

```js
bounds = map.getBounds();
NEPoint = bounds.getNorthEast();
SWPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

To then get the lat/lng values of each of those points so you can use it with Parse.GeoPoint, you should be able to do something like this (I'm not familiar with Parse, but got this [from their docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_withinGeoBox)):

```js
northEastCorner = new Parse.GeoPoint(NEPoint.lat(), NEPoint.lng());
southWestCorner = new Parse.GeoPoint(SWPoint.lat(), SWPoint.lng());

query = new Parse.Query.withinGeoBox(key, southWestCorner, northEastCorner);
```

Comment: b = map.getBounds();
  
  var bounds = {
    "ne": b.getNorthEast(),
    "sw": b.getSouthWest()
  };
  console.log("Map Bounds: ", JSON.stringify(bounds)); Result: Map Bounds: , {"ne":{},"sw":{}}

Comment: what's your point?  getNorthEast isn't returning a JSON string... it's a LatLng object, which you can then use with the map.

Comment: I want to convert it to Parse.Query.withinGeoBox

Comment: ... right, you should have made that part of your original question. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLngBounds) the `getBounds()` method returns a `google.maps.LatLngBounds` object. You are seeing the result of its `toString` method. You need to do something like:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

Be sure that you understand that the NE and SW objects are `google.maps.LatLng` objects.